# Jacobi field along a geodesic that has two conjugate point can not have tangential component?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $\gamma:[a,b] \to M$ be the geodesic on Riemann manifold with two conjugate point $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ then exist a Jacobi field between this two point.Prove that $J(t)$  and $D_tJ(t)$ does not have tangential component?

My attempt,since $J = J^\perp + J^T$ both of the component are Jacobi field,since tangential Jacobi field that vanishes at two different points are indentical zero,hence $J(t)$ does not have tangential component.

Next since for $D_t J$ along the geodesic we have $D_t\gamma'(t)= 0$,hence $$0=D_t (J^T) = \langle D_tJ ,\gamma'\rangle\gamma' = (D_t J)^T$$ hence $D_tJ$ as well has no tangential component.Is my idea correct?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: thank you $\ \ \ \ $